# Objective Sharpie won't install after installing MonoFramework-MDK-4.0.4.4.macos10.xamarin.x86.pkg

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm new to Xamarin and was just following along with the Binding Objective-C walkthrough. Got to the part where I'm supposed to install Objective Sharpie and the installation is telling me to install Mono:

"Objective Sharpie requires the Mono framework to be installed (3.2 or later). You can download the latest version of the Mono framework here: http://mono-project.com/Download"

Followed the link and installed from the mono .pkg but Objective Sharpie still tell me it needs mono before it can install. I rebooted, was able to compile a Mono program from the command line, still getting the message from Objective Sharpie.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Which version of sharpie are you installing? Wondering since sharpie 3.0.8 only checks to see of the OS-X version is 10.9.0 or above (even though it states 10.10 on the website) http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/objective_sharpie/

Answer (score 1):

The error happens with ObjectiveSharpie version "1.1.1".
Try to download and install the latest version of ObjectiveSharpie and you will not encounter this problem.
https://files.xamarin.com/~abock/ObjectiveSharpie/latest